# Error al conectar vuejs con firebase usando vue-fire

Tags: firebase, vue.js

Estoy intentando conectar `vue.js` con `firebase` usando la librería `vue-fire`.
Aquí tengo mi fichero `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
      <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Vuejs Firebase Database</a>
    </nav>
    <!-- Main Content -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-5">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3>Add A New Website</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <form @submit.prevent="addWebsite">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newWebsite.name" placeholder="Name">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newWebsite.author" placeholder="Author">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newWebsite.url" placeholder="URL">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Save</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8 text-center">
            <img src="./assets/logo.png">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3>Websites List</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Author</th>
                      <th>Operations</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="w in websites">
                      <td>
                        <a v-bind:href="w.url" target="_blank">{{w.name}}</a>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {{w.author}}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import Firebase from 'firebase';
import config from './config.js';
let app = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
let db = app.database();
let websitesRef = db.ref('websites');

export default {
  name: 'App',
  firebase: {
    websites: websitesRef
  },
  data() {
    return {
      newWebsite: {
        name: '',
        author: '',
        url: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addWebsite() {
      websitesRef.push(this.newWebsite);
      this.newWebsite.name = '';
      this.newWebsite.author = '';
      this.newWebsite.url = '';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Y la consola me marca el siguiente error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "websites" is not defined on the
> instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at src/App.vue
>  warn @ vue.esm.js?efeb:628

Todo esto es mientras intento seguir un tutorial de fazt para aprender a integrar estas dos tecnologías.
¿Tienen alguna idea de por qué la propiedad me está fallando?

Comment: Lo que te está diciendo no es un error de `firebase`, si no de `vue`. Dice que está intentando renderizar una variable que no existe en el "data" de vue.

Comment: @jBaumann gracias, me di cuenta tarde, pero en el tutorial el no la pone e igual funciona, porque existe este objeto Firebase que se encarga de eso.

Comment: ¿Sigues con el problema? ¿Qué tutorial estás siguiendo? ¿por qué has creado un "bloque" llamado firebase? ¿Estás usando vue-fire o similar?

Comment: @jBaumann si, sigo con el mismo problema y estoy usando vue-fire. He visto la documentacion y es tal cual lo explica el tutorial.

Comment: Deberías haber puesto en la pregunta que estabas usando `vue-fire`. Si quieres te puedo poner un ejemplo para usarlo sin `vue-fire`, solo con javascript.

Comment: @jBaumann ya actualicé la pregunta. Me interesa con vue-fire. Saludos.

Comment: En que ejemplo te dice que no uses el data para guardar datos? eso "violaria" lo que dice vue, y por eso el error...

Answer (score 0):

No se si ya ha trabajado con firebase y javascript antes pero si no es así, le aconsejo que haga el script de firebase por aparte con javascript puro o jquery primero y luego trate de hacerlo con vue para que primero entienda firebase.
Aquí un ejemplo con jquery:

```
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var count=0;
var countt=0;
var total=0;

    const dbref=firebase.database().ref().child('Modulo Clientes');
    dbref.on('value',function(snapshot){

        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var k=childSnapshot.key;
    var childData =childSnapshot.val();
var est='';
if(childData.Estado.toUpperCase().includes('SIN INICIAR')){
    est='<font color="red">'+childData.Estado+'</font>';
}
else if(childData.Estado.toUpperCase().includes('EN PROCESO')){
    est='<font color="yellow">'+childData.Estado+'</font>';
}
else{
    count--;
    est='<font color="green">'+childData.Estado+'</font>';
}
 count++;
 countt++;
     const table='<tr><td>'+countt+'</td><td>'+childData.Tarea+'</td><td>'+childData.ValorOptimista+'</td><td>'+childData.ValorMedio+'</td><td>'+childData.ValorPesimista+'</td><td>'+((parseFloat(childData.ValorOptimista)+parseFloat(childData.ValorMedio)+parseFloat(childData.ValorPesimista))/3).toFixed(2)+'</td><td>'+est+'</td></tr>';

            $('#tabla').append(table);

            total+=Number((((parseFloat(childData.ValorOptimista)+parseFloat(childData.ValorMedio)+parseFloat(childData.ValorPesimista))/3).toFixed(2)));


  });

$('#count').html(count);
    $('#total').html(total);

    });



</script>
```

Donde "Modulo Clientes" es el nodo padre de la BD.
Otra opción seria utilizar firebase como REST.En la documentación vienen los endpoints.

Comment: Sabes remediarlo con Vuejs?

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>

 import Firebase from 'firebase';
 import config from './config.js';
 let app = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
 let db = app.database();
 let websitesRef = db.ref('websites');
 import toastr from 'toastr'


 export default {
     name: 'App',
     data() {
         return {
             websites:[],
                newWebsite: {
                     name: '',
                     author: '',
                     url: ''
                }
             }
         },
         created() {
             Firebase.database().ref('websites').on('value', (snapshot) => {
                 this.websites = snapshot.val() 
             })
         },     
         methods: {
             addWebsite() {
                 websitesRef.push(this.newWebsite);
                 this.newWebsite.name = '';
                 this.newWebsite.author = '';
                 this.newWebsite.url = '';
                 toastr.success('Registro modificado correctamente.', 'Aviso');
             }
        }
 }
 </script>
```

```html
// Try this and tell me
<template>
     <div id="app">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
             <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Vuejs Firebase Database</a>
         </nav>
    <!-- Main Content -->
         <div class="container">
             <div class="row mt-5">
                 <div class="col-sm-4">
                     <div class="card">
                         <div class="card-header">
                             <h3>Add A New Website</h3>
                         </div>
                         <div class="card-body">
                             <form @submit.prevent="addWebsite">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                     <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newWebsite.name" placeholder="Name">
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                     <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newWebsite.author" placeholder="Author">
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                     <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newWebsite.url" placeholder="URL">
                                 </div>
                                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Save</button>
                             </form>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-8 text-center">
                     <img src="./assets/logo.png">
                    <div class="card">
                         <div class="card-header">
                             <h3>Websites List</h3>
                         </div>
                         <div class="card-body">
                             <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                 <thead>
                                     <tr>
                                         <th>Name</th>
                                         <th>Author</th>
                                         <th>Operations</th>
                                     </tr>
                                 </thead>
                                 <tbody>
                                     <tr v-for="w in websites" v-bind:key="w['.id']">
                                         <td>
                                             <a v-bind:href="w.url" target="_blank">{{w.name}}</a>
                                         </td>
                                         <td>
                                             {{w.author}}
                                         </td>
                                         <td>
                                             <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                         </td>
                                     </tr>
                                 </tbody>
                             </table>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</template>
```